# PowerPivot DAX formula for getting values when date is last year

Tags: excel-formula, powerpivot, dax

I am looking for a DAX formula in PowerPivot that shows last year value when date is previous year.

I have the following data (table)
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvZCc.png)

I want to have a new column called "LastYear_Count" that shows values from previous year. For instance: Row Date:2/28/2017 - Branch: North - Count: 8 - LastYear_Count: 5 (since count value for last year 2/28/2016 was 5)

Answer (score 1):

```
Count Lastyear = CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[Count]);FILTER(Table1;Table1[Branche]=EARLIER(Table1[Branche]) && DATEADD(Table1[Date];1;YEAR)=EARLIER(Table1[Date])))
```

Result:

[image: snip]

Note: I've used the SUM aggregation, assuming there's only one 'count' for each day / branche combination. If this is not the case, please let us know.

Comment: It worked beautifully.. Thanks a lot.. I have applied to a PivotTable as well and I can now have current counts along with previous year counts.